# How to call an HTTPS URL using a certificate?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am redirecting to an URL using this line in MVC:

`return Redirect("https://myurl.com);`

But when browser is redirected it asks from a certificate, and I don't want to user needs to select his certificate on browser, I would like to redirect to that URL already passing a certificate. 
How could I do that?

Comment: Are you seeing this in a deployed production environment or when you test locally?

Comment: @maccettura I am publishing on my own `IIS`. So I think that it's similar to an 'production environment'

Comment: Have you already configured an SSL certificate on your domain?

Comment: @maccettura What domain? Look that my application is calling another whatever URL witch I don't have access to the environment.

Comment: In your post you are redirecting to `"https://myurl.com"` which to me seemed like it was a URL that you controlled.  Is that not the case?  If that URL is something that you do not control, and it is prompting users to install a certificate then what are you expecting to have the power to do?

Comment: @maccettura  I think that I wasn't clear, could be my bad English... I am trying to open an HTTPS url, which requires a certificate, the browser shows a dialog with all the installed certificates, I can choose one and continue. I would like to skip this "dialog step", when my MVC application redirect to the another page, already pass the certificate programatically.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do that with redirect, in principle.

Comment: @Evk but you know how to do without Redirect? I am doing "Redirect" because I don't know another way

Comment: No I don't think it's possible. If you own https://myurl.com, you can configure server to restrict possible client certificate list as much as possible, and if just one certificate will be left - browser might send it automatically. If you don't own https://myurl.com - there is nothing you can do.

Comment: You could proxy the redirect, so actually request the page in your application and pass the client certificate yourself and return the resulting page.